# PHP Nuke to WordPress migration URL redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, migration

I have to migrate a medium-sized site based on PHP Nuke (less than 2000 posts) to a new WordPress installation. I have problems writing the redirection rules. I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=News&file=article&sid=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^nuke/modules.php$ http://domain.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

So

```
http://domain.com/nuke/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=1
```

should become

```
http://domain.com/1
```

It doesn’t work. I tried the .htaccess file in the “nuke”, “modules” and “News” folder with not luck. Any help would be very appreciated.

Here's the working code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=News&file=article&sid=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^modules.php$ http://domain.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the htaccess file in the "nuke" folder, you need to omit the `nuke` from the pattern:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=News&file=article&sid=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^modules.php$ http://domain.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

And make sure you've turned on the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The rewrite engine was turned on in the root but not in the subfolder. Works like a charm now. Thank you very much for your help.